# Facebook php sdk 3.2.1 + javascript login infinite loop

Tags: php, cookies, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, session-cookies

The problem may seem a duplicate of many other facebook connect login loop issues but it's not since it refers to the latest php sdk version (3.2.1) available at the moment. All the older questions refer to other versions, or solution provided don't fit this case.

Shortly: using php sdk 3.2.1 for session management and javascript sdk to get a popup login instead of a page redirection generates an infinite loop on certain browsers.  The example itself provided in the sdk does not work on Chrome.

The problem is better explained on the facebook dev site [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/172040042942772) (no-one solved it, perhaps they will just include a fix on the new release).

It seems to concern the cookie management. 
Any idea of how to patch it?

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to this recent bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/238039849657148

Try upgrading to the latest version of the PHP-SDK (3.2.2).

Comment: No way, the problem is still there :(

Comment: Bugger. There are users still reporting similar issues even with 3.2.2. See here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/181323008674971